# Dropbox module can't find SSL certificate after using PyInstaller

Tags: python, ssl, dropbox, python-3.5, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build an executable file from my Python-3.5 code that downloads files from Dropbox via PyInstaller.  This works fine when running the pure Python code, but the executable can't seem to find/freeze urllib3's ssl_.py.  I can't figure out how to resolve this issue--any help would be appreciated.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 226, in request
  File "site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 244, in urlopen
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
  File "site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 310, in ssl_wrap_socket
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
  File "SIPM_v3_ATO_trace.py", line 1201, in <lambda>
    runbutton_forecast = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Execute Forecast Model", command=lambda: run_rcode())
  File "SIPM_v3_ATO_trace.py", line 557, in run_rcode
    print('Linked account: ', client.account_info())
  File "site-packages\dropbox\client.py", line 155, in account_info
  File "site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 317, in GET
  File "site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 254, in GET
  File "site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 232, in request
dropbox.rest.RESTSocketError: Error connecting to "https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info": SSL certificate error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```